# Python dictreader KeyError issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am getting a keyerror when trying to read data from a csv. Below is the code that writes to the csv, followed by the code that reads from it. Python 2.7 on Ubuntu. Any help is appreciated!

```
    #setting up the csv
with open(databaseLocal, 'wb') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['cpu', 'pid', 'memory']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, 
            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        writer.writeheader()

#Here is one spot where it's written to...
if data[:6] == 'active':
                print 'mem info received'
                memInfo = data[7:-1]

                writer.writerow({'cpu': '_', 'pid': pidValue, 'memory': memInfo})

#and here is where it's read from, there is a KeyError for the line
#where we try to get row['pid]
with open(d, 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
        for row in reader:
            print row['pid']
            print row.keys()
```

When I just print 'row.keys()' all three of the keys show up. Not sure why I can't access 'row['pid'] or any of the others.

Thanks!
   Matt

Answer (score 1):

You are writing to `databaseLocal`, but trying to read from `d`. Are you sure they are referencing the same file?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have included the previous line, which is 'for d in dbList:' and that databaseLocal should be included in dbList. If I comment out the print row['pid'] and just leave print row.keys(), I can clearly see that the rows are there.

Comment: If I just say print row instead of print row['key'], it prints out this '{'cpu,pid,memory': '_,13330,1336811520'}
'

Comment: It looks like the reader incorrectly parses the file. Try setting the `fieldnames` parameter when creating the `DictReader`: `reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, quotechar='|')`

Comment: OK here's an interesting development! It does work to say 'print row['cpu,pid,memory']'. It then prints out all three values. Did I somehow make it all one big key?

Comment: Yes, looks like you did. As I said, the `DictReader` incorrectly parses the input, so you need to specify the `fieldnames`.

Comment: I tried adding fieldnames=field... into the dictreader and got this error 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 127, in <module>
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, quotechar='|')
NameError: name 'fieldnames' is not defined
' EDIT: Looks like I'll need to put down the fieldnames variable again.